# Best way to filter traffic in php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, traffic

I am developing an android application (begginer) that will manage a database on a server using http requests to a php file system.
My question is: What is the best way to restrict traffic to those php files? because I only want those php files to be executed by requests from my application and not by request from other programs(postman),services, etc ...

Comment: Create an API to connect to your server through HTTPS using HMAC authentication scheme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to disallow your API for any particular client. You can reject the request based on the source IP or port, the headers including user agent, API keys or other credentials, but if your API can be accessed at all, then it can be accessed by postman or any other client using the same data.

To limit the way how people can access the data you can add API keys and user credentials, but the same user with the same API key and credentials will be able to access your API using any other software and there is no way around it.

One thing you could do would be to e.g. require some headers that are restricted for postman - see Restricted headers and cookies in the Postman documentation:

Comment: Of course there's plenty of other tools, like curl, that would ignore any of Postman's restrictions.  In the end, your first half is right-  you can restrict access to a user (with a shared secret), but not to a client.